# display:none not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a gallery that only open when the user click on the button. So I have add the code display:none because i dont want display the gallery at the start. But when I click on the button only open the background and the images dont show.

Any idea what is the problem?

```
<a onClick="$('.fixed-bar').toggle('slow');" data-icon="grid" data-iconpos="notext" data-inline="true" class="ui-btn-right" data-direction="reverse" style="margin-right:70px">Paginas</a>

<div class="container demo-3">
    <div class="main">
        <div class="fixed-bar" style="display:none">
            <ul id="carousel" class="elastislide-list">
                <li><a href="#"><img src="elastislide/small/1.jpg" alt="image01" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="elastislide/small/2.jpg" alt="image02" /></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $( '#carousel' ).elastislide( {
        minItems : 2
    } );
</script>
```

Comment: Is that the complete code? Where do you close div#fixed-bar?

Comment: Where do you have the button click?

Comment: What button?  You've left most of your HTML tags open too.

Comment: do the images show, if you don't start with display:none? perhaps the jQuery plugin needs to be initiated/started?

Comment: yes they show..  if i delete display:none: its start automaticaly to show the gallery and works fine, but i want that the user decide to see or not when he clicks on the button

Comment: You have jQuery inside of an inline `click` handler. ugh.  Why not just use a jQuery `.click()` handler?  See:  http://api.jquery.com/click/   While you're at it, Google the difference between `display:none` and `visibility: hidden`.

Comment: I would check the display property of .elastislide-list after you toggle(), and see if it is also retaining :none.

Comment: @user2232273 - PLEASE format your code and markup properly when you post questions - I see multiple instances of this issue with your questions - help us help you by proper question formation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little off topic, but it's generally better to not write your jQuery/CSS inline like that - it's better to place them in external files for maintenance and performance reasons.

Here's a working **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/69Sfx/8/)**.

Btw, I've used that particular link's class '`ui-btn-right`' as the selector here in the jQuery and CSS - you should probably give that particular link an ID or something to use as it's selector, unless that's the only time you plan on using that class.

**jQuery:**

```
$('.ui-btn-right').on('click', function(){
  $('.fixed-bar').toggle('slow');
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<a data-icon="grid" data-iconpos="notext" data-inline="true" class="ui-btn-right" data-direction="reverse">Paginas</a>   
<div class="container demo-3">
   <div class="main">
     <div class="fixed-bar">   
       <ul id="carousel" class="elastislide-list">
         <li><a href="#"><img src="elastislide/small/1.jpg" alt="image01" /></a></li>
         <li><a href="#"><img src="elastislide/small/2.jpg" alt="image02" /></a></li>
       </ul>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.ui-btn-right {
  margin-right:70px;      
}

.fixed-bar {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: In defense of the OP that inline stuff came from another poster in response to a question which could probably be improved as an answer.

Comment: cant see the images.. its works.. but i can only see the background and the images not..  thanks for your help

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss That's fair enough, hopefully he knows it was just some constructive advice and I was just trying to help!

Comment: @user2232273 That's to do with your file paths - your images must not be in the correct folder, as my code works fine, look here's my example with images from the internet - http://jsfiddle.net/69Sfx/7/ - it's the same code just with different img url's.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using some sort of javascript gallery to do a carousel effect. You may need to used `style="visibility: hidden"` instead.  The script may be calculating sizes on beginning and `display:none` objects wont have these sizes.

**EDIT**:
Since you are using a plugin I still standby my visibility:hidden solution.  It doesn't look like you have your plugin linked for reference but I am guessing it is the elastislide-responsive-carousel.

Looking at the source of this plugin it looks like it calls outerWidth and outerHeight on the images to store them for later use in the plugin at line 340.

The issue is that it is storing 0. I've modified the jsfiddle previously posted to show this here.

http://jsfiddle.net/Z6DhF/1/

As suggested by others instead of using the inline, try this code

**CSS**

`.fixed-bar {
 visibility: hidden
}`